# (UIView *)hitTest in viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to use:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

in viewcontroller.m file?

Answer (score 9):

`hitTest:withEvent:` method is declared in UIView class so you it can't be used in UIViewController subclasses directly.

But other touch-tracking methods such as `touchesBegan:withEvent:` etc are declared in UIResponder and so can be implemented in both UIView and UIViewController subclasses

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps an alternative workaround is simply to subclass UIView , and in your init function of view controller  assign the view controllers view to that UIView.

Eg.
NavPanelViewController.m

```
- (id)init

    theView = [[NavPanelView alloc]init]; // declare theView in your header and in dealloc release
    self.view = theView;
```

Then you can override the pointInside method in your subclass.

Comment: I don't know why your is not the accepted answer, as it is the only one that truly answers the question.

Comment: Best practice would be to set a custom UIView in `-loadView`. The reason being to avoid prematurely loading the view.

Answer (score 3):

You can always define a specific delegate for handling the hitTest relevant info. In the `hitTest:withEvent:` in your UIView class's .m (implementation) file call the delegate's method, passing all your relevant info to the delegate to handle. Declare your ViewController class to implement the delegate like this:

```
@implementation MyViewController: UIViewController <HitTestDelegate>
```

This way, the actual implementation of the logic following user's tap will be in the MyViewController class.